# Two dropdownmenus in one form

Tags: php, html, select, post

I have declared and loaded two dropdownmenus successfully in one form with a Submit input.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<select name="sel1">
<?php //dynamically load options ?>
</select><br>

<select name="sel2">
<?php 
$opt1= (isset($_POST['sel1'])? $_POST['sel1'] : null);
$Arr = array();
if ($opt1 != null){//loads options into $Arr}
foreach($Arr as $option)
{
    if($option== $_POST['sel2']){
        echo "<option selected='$selected'>{$option}</option>";    
    }
    else{
        echo "<option>{$option}</option>";
    }
}
?>

</select>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<?php
$var1 = (isset($_POST['sel1'])? $_POST['sel1'] : null);
$var2 = (isset($_POST['sel2'])? $_POST['sel2'] : null);
?>
```

I select an option for sel1 and click submit, then `sel2` loads options depending on selection of `sel1`. Then I select `sel2` and click Submit. The PHP script does some processing based on the selections.

However `$_POST` is only able to get the value from sel1, `$var2` is always `null`. Any ideas of where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you post the HTML after performing the second select?

Comment: What kind of validation on this form is going on?  Perhaps you have a JS `=` where you meant `==`?

Comment: It would help if you post the php that dynamically loads options for sel2

Comment: You set `$Arr = array();`, have you removed the content? If this is "live" code, then `$Arr` will always be empty and no options are added to `sel2. Can you actually choose anything in the second dropdown?

Comment: Yes the options for sel2 have been loaded. It's just after I Submit again, the value selected for sel2 is null.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML generated y the PHP? (go to the page, right click, view source, then copy the html)

Comment: can you do a print_r on $_POST and show us what your getting

Answer (score 1):

$Arr is an empty array. So, basically every time you click submit, the php code that is supposed to populate sel2 doesn't work as you expect it. You need to add your options to $Arr right after this line:

```
$Arr = array();
```

Comment: sel2 is populated correctly. It's just that after I submit again, $_POST can't seem to get the value that was submitted for sel2.